# Rest-API V2 How to load specifiv Posts by ID?

Tags: wordpress, rest

I am using

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/wordpress-dev/mi/wp-json/wp/v2/cpt/',
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
});
```

to load posts of a custom post type.

I have an array with ids and i need to modify the url to load only the posts with this ids. How is this possible?

something like:

```
url: 'http://localhost/wordpress-dev/mi/wp-json/wp/v2/cpt/1&2&3
```

thanks alot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anybody needs this:

`post__in` must be used as array, like this:

`url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/cpt?filter[post__in][]=1&filter[post__in][]=2&filter[post__in][]=3'`

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, you should be able to specify a filter such as:

```
http://localhost/wordpress-dev/mi/wp-json/wp/v2/cpt?filter[p]=1,2,3
```

The filters are taken from the [WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) class.

Comment: thanks a lot, it seems to load only the first post `1`, what can i do? to load all posts `1,2,3`, thanks!

Comment: it seems i need to use `post__in` but this is also not working, what can i do?